# High Charts - area chart with gradient & threshold

Tags: highcharts

I have an area chart with a variable threshold; I've drawn a line for that value.

Is it possible to have one color for the fill above the threshold, and one color for the fill below it?

I have a gradient that fits the bill if the graph crosses the line, but not if the data is all below the line or all above it.

(Will attempt to update my question with a jsfiddle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is an old question, I feel I should answer it anyway:

I split the series in two, and added the "dummy" median value (the threshold) in place of any value that was in the "wrong" series.

data `[1, 2, 5, 8, 6, 4, 3, 10]` with threshold `5`

was split into:

data 1 `[5, 5, 5, 8, 6, 5, 5, 10]` color green

data 2 `[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5]` color red

As I was drawing a black line at `5` anyway, the graphs look correct. I also had to modify the 'hover' function to show the original Y value, not the value form the split series.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish this would be to use an `arearange` chart.  Instead of just one data set in your area chart, you would have two data sets in the area range, one for each shaded area. see http://jsfiddle.net/gXpHH/2/